# Uninitialized constant from factory_girls when testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, integration-testing, rspec2, factory-bot, initialization

I'm using Rails 3.2.1 with factory_girl_rails and I've got a problem, here is my factories.rb file:

```
require factory_girl
  ##defining room requests
  Factory.define :room_request do |rr|
    rr.starts_at '2012-02-06 08:00:00 UTC'
    rr.ends_at '2012-02-06 17:00:00 UTC'
    rr.request_type 'normal request'
    rr.number_of_participants 5
    rr.bookers_name 'Tester'
    rr.number_of_microphone 3
    rr.status 'waiting'
    rr.room_id 1
  end

  Factory.define :wrong_room_request do |wrr|
    wrr.starts_at ''
    wrr.ends_at ''
    wrr.request_type ''
    wrr.number_of_participants 0
    wrr.bookers_name 'r'
    wrr.number_of_microphone 0
    wrr.status ''
    wrr.room_id ''
  end
```

And my room_request_spec.rb file:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe RoomRequest do

  it "accepts if room is selected" do
    room_request = Factory(:room_request)
    room_request.room_id.should_not be_nil
    room_request.should be_valid
  end

  it "rejects when room is not selected" do
    wrong_room_request = Factory(WrongRoomRequest)
    wrong_room_request.room_id.should be_nil
    wrong_room_request.should_not be_valid
  end

end
```

When I'm running my test by `rspec spec/models/room_request_spec.rb` I've got:

```
Failures:

  1) RoomRequest rejects when room is not selected
     Failure/Error: wrong_room_request = Factory(WrongRoomRequest)
     NameError:
       uninitialized constant WrongRoomRequest
     # ./spec/models/room_request_spec.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I don't know how to initialize it, plz help :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call a Factory with a symbol, not a constant.

```
wrong_room_request = Factory(:wrong_room_request)
```

Update your `factories.rb` file to the new syntax as follows:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :room_request do
    starts_at '2012-02-06 08:00:00 UTC'
    ends_at '2012-02-06 17:00:00 UTC'
    request_type 'normal request'
    number_of_participants 5
    bookers_name 'Tester'
    number_of_microphone 3
    status 'waiting'
    room_id 1
  end

  factory :wrong_room_request do
    starts_at ''
    ends_at ''
    request_type ''
    number_of_participants 0
    bookers_name 'r'
    number_of_microphone 0
    status ''
    room_id ''
  end
end
```

Finally, I assume you are using the factory_girl_rails gem. So to make sure it is set up properly your `gemfile` should include:

```
group :test do
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', :require => false
end
```

And your `spec_helper.rb` should include

```
require 'factory_girl_rails'
```

Comment: Strange - let's try and knock the Factory into shape - you are using an old syntax and you don't need to `require` if your factory files are in the `/spec/factories/` folder. I will add to my answer.